# Tone of voice expressing anger, frustration, and impatience

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, adjectives, adverbs

Is there a specific word for this? I've looked for a bit, and have returned with the word *sharp*
I'm wondering if there is another word of this.

An example sentence would be
"Jane yelled back in a _____ voice."

I'm repeating both in the same paragraph, so I would like to reduce redundancy.
(edit: I forgot to add, loud. Loud voice expressing anger, frustration and impatience)

Comment: Maybe what you need is “Jane snarled (or growled)—a verb that expresses her feelings. Or “snarled in anger”. Hard to pack it in one word, but yell doesn’t explicitly do anger, frustration, or impatience. Snapped?

Comment: Oh, by the way, off-topic, but is "sharp" the right word to use? I've only seen it on one site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ow about **strident**? From Lexico:

> **[strident](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/strident)**: Loud and harsh; grating; ‘his voice had become increasingly sharp, almost strident’

Your example:

> Jane yelled back in a **strident** voice.

**Strident** certainly captures *loud* prompted by *anger*, *frustration*, and *impatience*.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

- An irate voice
- An exasperated voice
- An apoplectic voice
- A seething voice
- An incensed voice
- An indignant voice
- A rankled voice
- An infuriated voice
- A vexed voice
- An ireful voice